# inject content from one react component to another onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

OK,so i am starting to get my head around ReactJs but keep getting stumped by one simple concept that is a doddle with plain old jQuery.

I want to be able to add to the content of one element on the screen when an on click event happens upon another. Following the [react tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) i completely understand the way they have achieved the adding to the comments list, the comment list is a child of the parent which is setting the state.. but surely this cannot be the only way as it feels very rigid and inflexible.

Here is a simple mockup of what I am trying to explain. On click of the button, i want to inject new content into the div with id "newComments".. 
JSBin: [http://jsbin.com/vokufujupu/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/kafulacufa/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx">

      var InputBox = React.createClass({
          clickHandler: function(){
              //Append a new string to the end of the existing copy in the copy box
              alert('after this alert the value of the button should be appended to the content of the div#newComments');

          },
          render: function() {
              return (
                      <div classNmae="copyBox">
                          <input type="button" name="inputButton" value="click me button" className="bbbc"
                          onClick={this.clickHandler}  />
                      </div>
              );
          }
      });

      var CopyBox = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
              return (
                 <div classNmae="copyBox">
                    <p>div#newComments:</p>
                    <div id="newComments"></div>
                 </div>
              );
          }
      });

      var Page = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
                return (
                  <div>
                      <CopyBox/>
                      <InputBox/>
                  </div>
              );
          }
      });

      React.render(
              <Page/>,
              document.getElementById('content')
      );

  </script>

  <!-- The equiv in plain old js -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function newContent(obj){
      document.getElementById('vanBox').innerHTML = document.getElementById('vanBox').innerHTML + obj.value;
    }
  </script>
  <div id="vanilaJsEquiv">
    <div id="vanBox"></div>
    <input type="button" value="ClickyClik" onclick="newContent(this)"/>
  </div>    

</body>
</html>
```

I've been hunting around google and the docs for yonks and cannot find the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react there is no concept of manipulating HTML / DOM. React is responsible just for rendering based on component state. Every component renders whatever it's current state is.

So you need to manipulate the state of other component. For that Facebook is using Flux. Which is a bit more complex workflow, but once you get it, it is actually pretty simple concept.

On one component click you dispatch an action. That action will trigger event, stores that are subscribed to that event will react and update internal state. After update, store emits change event, all components listening for changes in that store will update.

Yes you will need to write a lot more code. It gets much simpler if component is manipulating it's own state, then it would be enough to just call `this.setState({ ... })` inside the component. And yes there, are other ways to do this.